React MUI DatePicker component display a string
I'm working on a feature where I need to make a MUI DatePicker component display "Today" when no date is selected.
DatePicker component display "Today"
The DatePicker is under moment adapter.
One method I could think is to pass the value "Today" to the DatePicker component but I got error because the DatePicker only accepts moment object.
The other method is to pass a valid moment object like today's date, then make the text field to display "Today", but I can not find a method to achieve that.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!
I passed the value "Today" to the DatePicker component but I got error because the DatePicker only accepts moment object.

It is not possible to show the text "Today" in the input field. What you do is use the current date and format it to "Today", "Tomorrow",  etc. And then show it next to MUI date picker.
